# How to append the current month and year to "Helpdesk Service" as dynamic column alias?

Tags: postgresql

My DB server is Postgresql.

Here is my sql query:

```
select 
scd.NAME AS "System", 
sum(case when udf_char1='Helpdesk Service' then 1 else 0 end) as "Helpdesk Service",
sum(case when udf_char1='Problem Determination and Management' then 1 else 0 end) as "Problem Determination and Management",
sum(case when udf_char1='System Status Monitoring and Problem Reporting' then 1 else 0 end) as "System Status Monitoring and Problem Reporting"
from SubCategoryDefinition scd
inner join CategoryDefinition cd On ((cd.CATEGORYNAME = 'Support System') OR (cd.CATEGORYNAME = 'Weather Info'))
and scd.categoryid=cd.categoryid 
left join WorkOrderStates wos ON wos.SUBCATEGORYID=scd.SUBCATEGORYID 
left join WorkOrder wo ON wo.WORKORDERID=wos.WORKORDERID 
left join WorkOrder_fields wf on  wo.WORKORDERID=wf.WORKORDERID 
group by  scd.SUBCATEGORYID
order by 1
```

For the "Helpdesk Service" column, I want to convert the column alias into "Helpdesk Service 12/2021", i.e. I want to append the current month and year after "Helpdesk Service",
how can I to implement it?

I have tried to use +,||, concat function to implement it, but no luck.

Comment: You  are not going to get that without converting your query to dynamic SQL ( imho not a good idea). Instead add a month-year as another column (yes it will be on all returned rows). Then lets your app's presentation manager append that column when needed, or just eliminate it from results  display.

Comment: As explained by @Belayer, the current month/year is not known before the run time, so you need a [dynamic query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) to do this.